# Spring Interceptor do not work JAVA

Tags: java, spring

I have these two classes in my project. When i use them in the config i can not submit the login form of the project. After i fill in my credentials and click login i try to debug the application and realize that the form do not hit the methot which makes the post request. I have no idea why but when a remove interceptor from the config i have no problems with login. Please help.

SessionInterceptor.class

```
 public class SessionInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private SessionManager sm;

        @Autowired
        private MessageSourceAccessor msa;

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
                throws Exception {

            String return_url = request.getRequestURL().toString() + "?" + request.getQueryString();
            return_url = return_url.replace(msa.getMessage("config.baseurl"), "");
            if (!request.getRequestURI().contains("login")) {
                if (sm.get(request) == null) {
                    response.sendRedirect(
                            msa.getMessage("config.baseurl") + "/login?return=" + URLEncoder.encode(return_url));
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
```

SessionManager.class

```
@Component
public class SessionManager {

    public static final String ProfileUser = "profileuser";

    public UserModel get(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = null;
        session = request.getSession(false);

        if (session == null)
            return null;
        return (UserModel) session.getAttribute(ProfileUser);
    }

    public void set(HttpServletRequest request, UserModel auth) {
        HttpSession session = null;
        session = request.getSession(false);

        if (session == null)
            return;

        session.setAttribute(ProfileUser, auth);
    }

    public void remember(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = null;
        session = request.getSession(false);

        if (session != null)
            session.invalidate();

        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60 * 60 * 60);
    }

    public void init(HttpServletRequest request, UserModel auth, Boolean remember) {
        HttpSession session = null;
        session = request.getSession(false);

        if (session != null)
            session.invalidate();

        session = request.getSession(true);
        if (remember)
            session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60 * 60 * 60 * 60);
        else
            session.setMaxInactiveInterval(1800);
        session.setAttribute(ProfileUser, auth);
    }

    public void destroy(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = null;
        session = request.getSession(false);

        if (session == null)
            return;

        session.removeAttribute(ProfileUser);
        session.invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with the interceptor?

Comment: I decided to do it in that way. What are the other options ?

Comment: Why do you need the interceptor?

Comment: I am trying to use it to prevent using the application from not logged in users.

Comment: That's what spring security is for, don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Ok. Please give some example.

Comment: [Go thru a quick start ](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) and ask specific questions if any

Answer (score 0):

Can u provide your whole configuration. As a wild guess from your code :

```
if (!request.getRequestURI().contains("login")) {
    if (sm.get(request) == null) {
        response.sendRedirect(
                msa.getMessage("config.baseurl") + "/login?return=" + URLEncoder.encode(return_url));
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now if your `sm.get(request) == null`then the redirection will happen, thus call will not go to controller.

Redirection means call again go to client, from where a new call will be initiated to the said url.

OR

if your `@Autowire` is not working in that case `sm` will be null. and `sm.get(request) == null` will throw `NullPointerException`. Again call will not go to controller.

But to sure, provide your configuration. OR debug your code in interceptor.